# Why does this Promise.all() not resolve even after all promises have resolved?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

For some reason Promise.all() is not firing even though all promises have been verified resolved. How could this happen or how can I debug this further?

The promises themselves are calling a 3rd-party library function that has a callback, and are being resolved in the callback.

```js
let promises = [];

for (let i = 0; i < payments.length; i++) {

    let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        setTimeout(() => {
            this.lib.createToken(result => {
                if (result.error) {
                    reject(false);
                    console.log('rejected', result.error.message);
                } else {
                    resolve(result.token);
                    console.log('resolved', result.token);
                }
            });
        }, (500 * i));

    });

    promises.push(p);
}

console.log('payment promises: ', promises.length);

Promise.all(promises).then(results => {

    console.log('promise all reached', results);

}).catch(reason => {
    console.log(reason);
});
```

This is console output:

```
payment promises: 2
resolved token1
resolved token2

// promise all reached – this is never reached!
```

The other weird thing is this happens only intermittently... like 1/10 times.

Edit:

If I set a breakpoint on Promise.all() it does show promises: Array(2) of ZoneAwarePromise's. Interestingly when using the breakpoint and resuming after, it will hang 100% of the time rather than intermittently without breakpoint.

Comment: That does look odd. Is that your complete code for that segment, without alterations? I'd suggest adding a `catch` to the end of the `Promise.all`, but that doesn't look to be the issue, since `rejected` isn't logged

Comment: I have removed my comment because it duplicated previous comment suggestion. :) If you are using native Promises and this is your real code final message should be logged. If this is not your actual code do try adding catch block, something is probably throwing.

Comment: @CertainPerformance yep that essentially the complete code, and yes there is a .catch which it doesn't hit... but createToken is always calling, cause I still see the console.log('resolved'...

Comment: @YuryTarabanko yes there is a .catch(), just added.. but I never see anything in the console after the 2 'resolved token' logs...

Comment: Interesting problem. Are you able to set a breakpoint on the `Promise.all` line to triple-check that the value of `promises` indeed contains 2 promises? Also, probably a long shot but any different behavior if you try `Promise.allSettled()` ?   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled

Comment: @Kevin I added a breakpoint on Promise.all in Chrome. The Scope > Local indeed shows promises: Array(2) of ZoneAwarePromise's. After resuming it will show the 2 'resolved token...' logs, then it hangs. Also interestingly it seems like if using the breakpoint then resuming after, it will hang 100% of the time rather than the intermittent behaviour without breakpoint.

Comment: It's curious they are labeled as "ZoneAwarePromises", when I searched for that I was led to Zone.js which seems to be part of Angular. Do you have an Angular app? All I can think is that somehow you have Zone.js (or another dependency) that is overriding the built-in Promise constructor and the promises you are getting are incompatible with `Promise.all()`. I realize that's a far-fetched idea. Sorry I don't have much else to offer!

Comment: @sm_j, this is a dangerous construction because an error in the `setTimeout` callback will not cause `new Promise()` to throw asynchronously. 
Instead, independently promisifiy `setTimout` (eg as `delay()`) and `this.lib.createToken` (eg as `this.lib.createTokenAsync()`) and chain the pieces together, eg `let p = delay(500 * i).then(this.lib.createTokenAsync).then(result => result.token);`. That will at least allow you reliably to observe errors downstream of `Promise.all()`, even if it doesn't fix the problem.